# Using red-black tree for non-linear optimization

Tags: optimization, data-structures, red-black-tree

Suppose we have finite data set `{x_i, y_i}`.

I am looking for an efficient data structure for the data set, such that given `a`,`b` it will be possible to find efficiently `x`,`y` such that `x > a`, `y > b` and `x*y` is minimal.

Can it be done using a red black tree ?

Can we do it in complexity O(log n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without a preprocessing step, of course you can't do it in `O(log n)` with any data structure, because that's not enough time to look at all the data. So I'll assume you mean "after preprocessing".

Red-black trees are intended for single-dimension sorting, and so are unlikely to be of much help here. I would expect a kD-tree to work well here, using a nearest-neighbor-esque query: You perform a depth-first traversal of the tree, skipping branches whose bounding rectangle either violates the x and y conditions or cannot contain a lower product than the lowest admissible product already found. To speed things up further, each node in the kD-tree could additionally hold the lowest product among any of its descendants; intuitively I would expect that to have a practical benefit, but not to improve the worst-case time complexity.

Incidentally, red-black trees aren't generally useful for preprocessed data. They're designed for efficient dynamic updates, which of course you won't be doing on a per-query basis. They offer the same asymptotic depth guarantees as other sorted trees, but with a higher constant factor.